# difficulty serializing a collection in web api 2 using knockoutjs

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api2

I have a knockoutjs web page doing a post to a VB .net Web API. for some reason my collection always shows nothing on the controller.

on the web page in the post here is my data.

```
 data: ko.toJSON({
                        ShpmntCntrlNbr: self.ShpmntCntrlNbr,
                        MstrBillNbr: self.MstrBillNbr,
                        accesorialChangesHaveBeenMade:      self.accesorialChangesHaveBeenMade,
                        DB2ACTCollection: actCollection
                    }),
```

this shows in the console (chrome developer tools) like this.

```
{
  "ShpmntCntrlNbr":"11019813",
  "MstrBillNbr":"          ",
  "accesorialChangesHaveBeenMade":true,
  "DB2ACTCollection":[
                      {"ShpmntCntrlNbr":"11019813"}
                     ]
 }
```

here is .net VB controller

```
Public Function Post(data As VMFreightReleaseSaveDB2ChangesInput) As IHttpActionResult 
        Return Ok()
    End Function
```

unfortunately when I put a stop sign in here and inspect data. I get

```
DB2ACTCollection  Nothing
MstrBillNbr "         "
ShpmntCntrlNbr "1101983"
accesorialChangesHaveBeenMade True
```

no clue why my DBACTCollection is showing as nothing. any thoughts?

and here are the classes.

```
Public Class VMFreightReleaseSaveDB2ChangesInput
    Public Property ShpmntCntrlNbr() As String
        Get
            Return m_ShpmntCntrlNbr
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_ShpmntCntrlNbr = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ShpmntCntrlNbr As String
    Public Property MstrBillNbr() As String
        Get
            Return m_MstrBillNbr
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_MstrBillNbr = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_MstrBillNbr As String
    Public Property accesorialChangesHaveBeenMade() As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_accesorialChangesHaveBeenMade
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            m_accesorialChangesHaveBeenMade = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_accesorialChangesHaveBeenMade
    Public Property DB2ACTCollection() As List(Of DB2_ACT2)
        Get
            Return m_DB2ACTCollection
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of DB2_ACT2))
            value = m_DB2ACTCollection
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_DB2ACTCollection As List(Of DB2_ACT2)
```

and

```
Public Class DB2_ACT2
    Public Property ShpmntCntrlNbr() As String
        Get
            Return m_ShpmntCntrlNbr
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_ShpmntCntrlNbr = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ShpmntCntrlNbr As String
End Class
```

Just a note here is my solution so far, not real happy with it but it seems to be working.  instead of data As VMFreightReleaseSaveDB2ChangesInput I have data as JToken.  then I just loop through it although I am still at a loss why the native .net web api serializer is not doing this.

```
 Dim inner As JArray = data("DB2ACTCollection")
        Dim ACTCollection = New List(Of DB2_ACT)
        For Each item As JObject In inner
            Dim ACT As New DB2_ACT
            ACT.ShpmntCntrlNbr = item("ShpmntCntrlNbr")
            ACTCollection.Add(ACT)
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the JSON and seeing as the models are POCOs try using auto properties with `DB2ACTCollection` as an array and see if that deserializes properly

```vb
Public Class DB2_ACT2
    Public Property ShpmntCntrlNbr As String
End Class

Public Class VMFreightReleaseSaveDB2ChangesInput
    Public Property ShpmntCntrlNbr As String
    Public Property MstrBillNbr As String
    Public Property accesorialChangesHaveBeenMade As Boolean
    Public Property DB2ACTCollection As DB2_ACT2()
End Class
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, nice thought makes sense unfortunately It is still showing Nothing. guess I'll just go with the Jtoken solution and move on. weird thing is I've done JSON to .net collections in the past with no problems.

Comment: I'm taking a shot in the dark, but have you tried adding a constructor to the db2act class per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29513909/net-web-api-deserialize-json-object-with-property-as-listof-object